# Using constant to declare an array of item

Tags: objective-c, arrays, constants, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to use some thing like this in Objective-C:

```
#define number_of_items 10
```

and then using it as:

```
int arr[number_of_items];
```

Comment: yes we can do it in the .m file, but not in .h file. i define a constant in .pch file and i want to use this constant in .hi file. is it possible?

Comment: I re-iterate: **why** are you editing PCH files?

Comment: it's a shared header file. i usually use it to define constant. but my problem not is .pch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming you mean *Objective* C. It's pretty much a superset of "proper" C so this is perfectly okay. It's also okay in both C and C++.

You can see that it works in the following transcript:

```
pax> cat qq.m
#import <objc/Object.h>

// First method.

#define number_of_items 10
int arr[number_of_items];

// Second method.

#define NUMBER_OF_ROWS 10
@interface test : Object{ int xyzzy[NUMBER_OF_ROWS]; }
@end;

pax> vi qq.m ; gcc -o qq.o -c qq.m -lobjc

pax> # no errors occurred
```

---

And, now that we've finally seen what you're *actually* using:

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define NUMBER_OF_ROWS_ (IS_IPAD? 18: 18)
```

`NUMBER_OF_ROWS_` is *not* a constant, since it depends on the return value of the function `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()`.

In other words, it cannot be calculated at compile time. That's why you're getting the error. You can see this by compiling the following code:

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define NUMBER_OF_ROWS_ (IS_IPAD ? 18: 20)

int UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM(void) {return 20;}
int UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad;

int main (void) {
    int arr[NUMBER_OF_ROWS_];
    return 0;
}
```

Under `gcc --pedantic`, you get:

```
qq.m: In function ‘main’:
qq.m:8: warning: ISO C90 forbids variable length array ‘arr’
```

You either need to use a dynamically adjustable collection like `NSMutableArray` or use an array of the maximum size desired and only use what you need of that.

Comment: i got this error: Instance variables must have a constant size

Comment: Then you're not using a define. It must be a variable.

Comment: i got this error: Instance variables must have a constant size
  
   @interface test : NSObject{
   
    int arr[NUMBER_OF_ROWS];
}

i had already defined NUMBER_OF_ROWS in shared header file .pch
what could be the reason here?

Comment: @phuongho, why are you mucking about with pre-compiled header files? They're not meant for users to edit, they're an aid to the build system. In any case, it's perfectly okay to use a `#define` to size an array so I have to conclude that `NUMBER_OF_ROWS` is _not_ one - you'll need to show more detail in the question.

Comment: imagine that you have an Ios project that base on an integer array which have NUMBER_OF_ROWS items. at the first you only want to make it small but after that you wan to make it lagre than. and the small or large belong to constant NUMBER_OF_ROWS. that the reason i want to use by this way!

Comment: If it's sized based on a #define, you can't make it larger without recompiling. If you want a resizable array, why aren't you using the collections, like NSMutableArray? That's what they're for: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableArray

Comment: #define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define NUMBER_OF_ROWS_ (IS_IPAD? 18: 18)
#define NUMBER_OF_COLS_ (IS_IPAD? 11: 11 ) then i still get error at int arrIn[NUMBER_OF_ROWS_];

Comment: yes of course. i must recompile the source again. the reason i hadn't use NSMutableArray is i want to use an old block of code. it's written in C